# Android Parental Control API

Tags: android, android-enterprise, parental-control

I wanted to know if Android SDK provides built-in api for parental control?

So far from my research I have seen it is possible to use background service and VPNService to restrict websites, screen time and applications but it need to be highly customized and very specific in order to achieve these.

I have also encountered [Android Enterprise][1] but, and correct me if I am wrong here, It is not a viable solution since the app I want to develop is meant to be uploaded to Play Store for the wide public to download.

I was wondering if there is a built-in feature/ framework that I missing in order to develop an application that can enforce parental control policies on the device.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to be clearer on the type of restrictions you want to put in place.  There is no Parental Control API.  There might be a way to do some of the things you want, but we need to know what.

Comment: Restricting websites, screen time and certain applications. As I wrote, I have general understanding of how to do it using VPNService and other background services, but it is not trivial to do so therefore I opened this thread to double check if maybe there is a straight forward api to do these restrictions

Comment: I can't speak on behalf of the OP, but consider the features of Family Link, things like:
make app installations ask permission from parent and block certain apps altogether, prevent usage of specific/all applications if screen time limits are reached, monitor usage of all applications, montior location of the device, allow wiping the device, etc..